# Logback programmatic configuration in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, logback, logback-classic

I'm trying to configure logback programmatically in Spring Boot.  I have a requirement to not use any XML files in my project. I'm using logback-extensions to create my logback appenders, etc.

```
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfig {

    @Bean
    // NOTE: THIS DOES NOT DO WHAT I EXPECT IT TO
    public LogbackConfigListener logbackConfigListener() {
        return new LogbackConfigListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public static ApplicationContextHolder applicationContextHolder() {
        return new ApplicationContextHolder();
    }

    @Bean
    public static LoggerContext loggerContext() {
        return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static LayoutWrappingEncoder encoder(LoggerContext ctx) {
        LayoutWrappingEncoder encoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(ctx);
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public static ConsoleAppender consoleAppender(LoggerContext ctx, LayoutWrappingEncoder encoder) {
        ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender();
        appender.setContext(ctx);
        appender.setEncoder(encoder);
        return appender;
    }

}
```

However, there is one step that I don't get from their documentation.  I am supposed to add a LogbackConfigListener to the web.xml.  How do I achieve this in Spring Boot?